# Link Linux C++ application statically via CMake 2.8

Tags: c++, linux, cmake

I have application built in Ubuntu 14.04 / GCC 4.8 / CMake 2.8 with -static-libgcc and -static-libstdc++. ldd command shows:

```
linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffc16195000)
libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007fcb18256000)
libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007fcb17f50000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007fcb17b8a000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x000055fc367e1000)
```

When I add -static to CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS - I got different output from ldd:

```
linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffd48349000)
libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007fe8d0335000)
libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007fe8d0031000)
libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007fe8cfd2a000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007fe8cf965000)
/lib/ld64.so.1 => /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x000055d61ec7d000)
libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007fe8cf74f000)
```

I supposed -static flag will result in static linked application. It did not happen.
May anyone explain me why ?

I have makefile generated by Qt Creator - with -static switch build results in fully static application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is from resulting CMakeLists.txt. I use -DSTATIC_LINKING=True when running CMake.

```
IF(STATIC_LINKING)
    SET(CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_SUFFIXES ".a")
ENDIF(STATIC_LINKING)


# libpcap library
find_library(pcap libpcap.a)

# opencore-amr libraries
find_library(opencore-amrnb libopencore-amrnb.a)
find_library(opencore-amrwb libopencore-amrwb.a)

# c++ netlib
find_library(cppnetlib-server-parsers libcppnetlib-server-parsers.a)
find_library(cppnetlib-uri libcppnetlib-uri.a)
find_library(cppnetlib-client-connections libcppnetlib-client-connections.a)

# pthread
find_library(pthread libpthread.a)

# boost libraries
set(Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS ON)
set(Boost_USE_MULTITHREADED ON)

# set -static, when STATIC_LINKING is TRUE and set LINK_SEARCH_END_STATIC
# to remove the additional -bdynamic from the linker line.
IF(STATIC_LINKING)
    SET(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "-static -static-libgcc -static-libstdc++"
    SET_TARGET_PROPERTIES(pvqa-server PROPERTIES LINK_SEARCH_END_STATIC 1)
ENDIF(STATIC_LINKING)
```

Answer (score 0):

`-static` is different from `-static-libgcc` and `-static-libstdc++` specifically in that `-static` does not assume static linking of standard libraries. Those two flags control this behavior.

To link statically with standard libraries, add those two flags to CMake `CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS` variable.

Comment: These flags are set already in CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS. True problem is resulting executable still depends on Linux dynamic libraries (see ldd output in post above). My goal is to make full static build.